# Python how to send a gtp packet using scapy. I tried converting the existing hex stream of gtp message but not able to create it properly

Tags: python, scapy, telecommunication

Python how to send a gtp packet using scapy. I tried converting the existing hex stream of gtp message but not able to create it properly.
some links are there but not ans is on it.
[scapy not parsing GTP layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402032/scapy-not-parsing-gtp-layers)

Comment: Found a way just use the scapy gtp library from layers.
Import the file and create hte GTP packet and send normally through scapy.

from scapy.layers.gtp import *

ipipu = ()
gtp_pkt = GTPHeader (type=255, TEID=1232, length= len (ippdu))/ippdu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example just tried,
first hex stream is as below

```
000c29dad1de000c29e3c64d08004500007c00004000401167bbc0a828b3c0a828b2086808680068bf6432ff00580000000128db0000450000540000400040015ea5ca0b289ec0a828b20800bee70000287b0411204bf43d0d0008090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334353637
```

enter scapy interactive mode and assign the above hex stream to a variable,

```
a = '000c29dad1de000c29e3c64d08004500007c00004000401167bbc0a828b3c0a828b2086808680068bf6432ff00580000000128db0000450000540000400040015ea5ca0b289ec0a828b20800bee70000287b0411204bf43d0d0008090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334353637'
b = a.decode('hex')
B = Ether(b)
B.show()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= 00:0c:29:da:d1:de
  src= 00:0c:29:e3:c6:4d
  type= 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version= 4L
     ihl= 5L
     tos= 0x0
     len= 124
     id= 0
     flags= DF
     frag= 0L
     ttl= 64
     proto= udp
     chksum= 0x67bb
     src= 192.168.40.179
     dst= 192.168.40.178
     \options\
###[ UDP ]###
        sport= 2152
        dport= 2152
        len= 104
        chksum= 0xbf64
###[ Raw ]###
           load= '2\xff\x00X\x00\x00\x00\x01(\xdb\x00\x00E\x00\x00T\x00\x00@\x00@\x01^\xa5\xca\x0b(\x9e\xc0\xa8(\xb2\x08\x00\xbe\xe7\x00\x00({\x04\x11 K\xf4=\r\x00\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567'
```

here scapy does not dissect and show GPRS, but we can still send out, i.e. windows nc

```
send(B, iface='Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260')
```

so the packet sent out with the interface, showing by wireshark is as 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Credit to chat gpt :)

```html
from scapy.all import IP, UDP, Raw
from scapy.contrib.gtp import GTPHeader

# Define GTP header fields
gtp_version = 1
gtp_type = 1  # GTP-U
gtp_length = 20  # GTP header length (in bytes)
gtp_teid = 12345  # Tunnel Endpoint Identifier
gtp_sequence_number = 0  # Sequence number
gtp_n_pdu_number = 0  # N-PDU number

# Create GTP header (as Raw layer)
gtp_header = GTPHeader(version=gtp_version, gtp_type=gtp_type, length=gtp_length, teid=gtp_teid, seq=gtp_sequence_number, npdu=gtp_n_pdu_number)

# Define GTP destination port
DPORT = 2152

# Create a UDP packet with source/destination ports (replace with actual values)
udp_packet = UDP(dport=DPORT)

# Create a payload (e.g., raw data) to include in the GTP packet
payload_data = b'This is a GTP packet payload.'

# Construct the final packet by combining IP, UDP, GTP headers, and payload
gtp_packet = IP(dst='1.2.3.4') / udp_packet / gtp_header / Raw(load=payload_data)

# Display the packet summary
print(gtp_packet.summary())

# Send the packet (replace 'eth0' with the appropriate interface)
# send(gtp_packet, iface='eth0')
```